# Invalid selector with querySelectorAll :not with descendants

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

I've got a case where I need to select different groups of nodes on a page, and I need to **exclude** certain child elements. My most common task is selecting all `<img>` elements, but not some that are descendants of certain elements.

Take for example my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rjdbys13/
I have 2 `<div>`s, each with an `<img>` inside. I want to select all images, but not ones within one of those `<div>`s (both with different classes).

To do so, and this works in jQuery and Sizzlejs, I can use a selector like `img:not(.amazingDiv img)`. To my understanding, this selects all `<img>` elements that are not a descendant of `<div>`s with a class containing `amazingDiv`. This works great as I said with libraries that support more-detailed `:not` syntax, but it fails with an error in `querySelectorAll`:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'img:not(.amazingDiv img)' is not a valid selector.`

I'd really like to avoid doing any "post processing" on the elements I collect, so is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for by using `querySelectorAll`? (I've also tried using the libraries ["qwery"](https://github.com/ded/qwery), "micro-selector" and "nut")

**Edit**: As my search for a selector combination to support some complex `:not` functionality was fruitless, I've opted for using a 3rd party selector engine - Jaguar (github.com/alpha123/Jaguar). It's not idea, and it's slower, but the end result is potentially more efficient as I won't need to "post process" my results.

Comment: Why to choose a negative condition when you can go for a positive one. `document.querySelectorAll(".amazingDiv2 img")`

Comment: @Vijay That would be completely correct, however I only used the second div with the class as an example. I effectively want all images **not** under an ancestor of some description.

Comment: What if you ignore the div itself, all the images under that would automatically be discarded.

`document.querySelectorAll("#parent div:not(.amazingDiv2) img")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector you are using is not correct according to specs:

> Selectors level 3 does not allow anything more than a single [simple
> selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors) within a :not() pseudo-class.
>
> [The negation pseudo-class, :not(X)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation), is a functional notation taking a
> simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
> argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its
> argument.

Comment: I was hoping this was not the case... And unlike regular functions there doesn't seem to be any easy way to polyfill this :(

Comment: AS @Vijay comment why not using `var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".amazingDiv img");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are looking to do is not possible with a standard CSS selector at this time. Currently, [`:not()` only accepts a single simple selector at a time](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation), so it is very limited in its usage.

In the upcoming standard, [`:not()` will be upgraded to allow combinators and complex selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#negation), bringing its functionality to par with what is offered by selector libraries. This means that, eventually, what you're using will be a valid selector once browsers get around to implementing the enhancement.

But in the meantime, assuming you can't already select the elements you want using a different selector that doesn't make use of `:not()`, you won't be able to do this without selecting all `img` elements and excluding `.amazingDiv img` separately (said "post processing" on those elements).

Answer (score 0):

What if you ignore the div itself, all the images under that would automatically be discarded.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#parent div:not(.amazingDiv2) img")
```

Comment: I can't see a problem with that - in fact it's so simple I can't believe I didn't try it. I do however make a lot of use of the `context` parameter of my query methods, for which I already have a HTMLElement instance.